# Finding birth records in Scotland?

Tags: birth-records, scotland

It seems to me that freebmd does not cover Scotland.

Are there any free resources that do?

The ones I found charge 7.50 just to see the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Freebmd only covers England and Wales, as it states on its [home page](https://www.freebmd.org.uk/)

ScotlandsPeople is your best starting point for Scotland; [this](https://www.scotlandspeople.gov.uk/content/our-charges) describes its credit-based charging structure. (Index searches are free).

For free records, you could try the [Scottish resources](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Scotland_Genealogy) at FamilySearch.

The paid-for sites (Ancestry, Findmypast etc.) also have Scottish records which you may be able to access for free at a local library.

[17 best free online Scottish resources](http://www.whodoyouthinkyouaremagazine.com/blog/17-best-free-online-scottish-resources) (written by Scottish genealogist Chris Paton will give you some other useful pointers if you need to delve deeper into Scottish records.

Comment: Thanks for that. On ScotlandsPeople it came up with: HARRIS, ALEXANDER, M, 1875, 595/29, IRVINE but I can;t locate this on FindMyPast.

Comment: I just wonder if this is Alexander Campbell Harris. The father is Samuel Harris and 1875 matches the death age.